# how to make function template more specialized

Tags: c++, overloading

Given the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// this is my custom streamer which functions like ostream:
// MyStream() << 123 << "456" << 2.0 << ...;
class MyStream {
public:
    template <typename T>
    // It only supports streaming basic types,such as int/float/char/char* ...
    MyStream& operator<<(T&& t) {
        // std::cout is just an example, actually I stream `t` to a buffer
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Test {
    int x;
    float y;
};

// I want to stream struct Test:
// MyStream() << Test();
// It will be more useful if I can stream `Test` to iostream or stringstream.
// std::cout << Test();
// std::stringstream ss;
// ss << Test();
// So I implemented a template operator overload function

template <typename Stream>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, const Test& t) {
    return s << t.x << ", " << t.y;
}

int main() {
    const Test t = {1, 2.0};
    MyStream ms;
    // but this doesn't work as expected
    ms << t;

    Test t2 = {3, 4.0};
    ms << t2;
}
```

It generates compiling error:

```
source>:26:8: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'MyStream' and 'const Test')
    ms << t;
    ~~ ^  ~
<source>:7:15: note: candidate function [with T = const Test &]
    MyStream& operator<<(T&& t) {
              ^
<source>:19:9: note: candidate function [with Stream = MyStream]
Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, const Test& t) {
        ^
1 error generated.
```

code link: https://godbolt.org/z/Gf51fjTMx

Acctually, `LogStream` is a wrapper around a third party library `fmt`, I want to make it works like `iostream`. But it does not support custom struct types.
So I added another overload function template `Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, const Test& t)` to allow streaming for custom struct.

Question:

How to make any of the two function overloads more specialized if I don't change the call site code (the `main` function)?

Comment: which one do you want to get called?

Comment: or why do you have both to start with?

Comment: Or why is `MyStream` not derived from `std::ostream`, so that operator for `Test` would not have to be template?

Comment: What is the *original* and underlying and actual problem you try to solve with code like that? Please always ask about the actual problem directly instead. Otherwise your question becomes just another [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Your idea itself is ambiguous. Your first method "can use MyStream to print anything", and your second function "can use any stream-like object to print Test". So, obviously they are equivalent. If `MyStream` acts as a forwarded to `std::ostream` for any kind of object, maybe restrict second function to only take `std::ostream`, not "any kind of stream".

Comment: `MyStream& operator<<(T&& t)` only supports basic types. I need a specialized version for custom struct type `Test`, which is `Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, const Test& t)`

Comment: @Bingo Unfortunately that's not what you have written in the code. `typename T` means *any* type-name, basic, classes, structures, aliases, anything that can be used as a type. I come back to my previous question: What is your actual problem that you need to solve? What is your assignment or exercise? What requirements and limitations do you have? Please [edit] your question to tell us all that.

Comment: I have added some description about my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class C, class T>
std::basic_ostream<C, T>& 
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<C,T>& s, const Test& t) {
    return s << t.x << ", " << t.y;
}
```

Better yest, do not write classes like `MyStream` at all, they tend to be fragile. If you need a specialised stream, derive your own from `std::basic_{i,o}stream` and/or write your own `streambuf` implementation.

Better still, ditch ostream formatting in favour of `std::format`.

Comment: I want to stream `Test` also to my custom streamer `MyStream`, not only `basic_ostream`. And don't want to make `MyStream` derive from `basic_ostream`.

Comment: can you give some explaination on why `MyStream` is fragile?

Comment: Either you have a catch-all `operator<<` which breaks overloads like that for your `Test` and you have to fix them all one by one like I show; or you have a restricted `operator<<` like shown in the other answer that doesn't work with types that have overloads for `std::ostream` (like `std::string` and an unknown number of third-party ones) and you need to manually fix those one by one. Either way it doesn't integrate well in what I do. But you do what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> // It only supports streaming basic types,such as int/float/char/char* ...

It is not reflected in signature.
You might add constraint for that:

```
template <typename T>
requires(std::integral<T>
      || std::floating_point<T>
      || std::is_pointer<T>::value
   /* || ..*/
    )
MyStream& operator<<(T t) {
    // std::cout is just an example, actually I stream `t` to a buffer
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

And then, that overload is no longer a viable candidate for `/* const */ Test /* & */`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oceKP7hq5)

Comment: Yes, this seems reasonable, and I thought of it. But it's hard to implement the `constraint`.

Comment: What is your actual constraints?

Comment: You can look at [this](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/8a4bec5cf53387356738a06ba0cf4fdf086241ae/include/fmt/core.h#L1334). Same as argument type as `map` function.

Comment: So you have all the condition already provided, it might just be long to enumerate/type. :-)

Comment: Trailing return type might be an alternative `auto operator<< (T t) -> decltype(std::declval<arg_mapper<Context>>().map(t), std::decval<MyStream&>())`.

Comment: or something like `requires (arg_mapper<Context> mapper) { {mapper.map(t) } -> not std::same_as<unformattable_pointer > };`.